# Add a string from a textbox to an array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I want to add a string from a textbox to an array, but when I tried to add it to the array it gives me an error (Cannot convert char[] to string[])
what is it that I'm doing wrong, and is it maybe a better way to do it?

```
    public string[] users = { "username" };
    public string[] passwords = { "password" };

    string[] users = textBox1.Text.ToArray();
    string[] passwords= textBox2.Text.ToArray();
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to do `string[] user = { textBox1.Text };` but why?

Comment: Why are you declaring string arrays for something that is a single string? You should probably make your `user` and `password` variables just strings as it doesn't seem like you are actually using an array, just single values. Then you can just assign directly from the `Text` property.

Comment: It really would help if you explained what you will be doing with these string arrays.

Comment: I want to add both a username and password to, later on, and be able to log in on a simple login screen

Comment: If by “a username and password” you mean one username and one password, you should be using strings, not string arrays. And if the password is for the username you should create a class that contains both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user` and `password` have been allocated as single element arrays. Arrays are immutable and cannot be appended to, so you cannot do this:

```cs
public string[] user = { "username" };
public string[] password = { "password" };
//...
user.Append(textBox1.Text);
password.Append(textBox2.Text);
```

But you could reallocate the `user` and `password` arrays with something like this:

```cs
public string[] user = { "username" };
public string[] password = { "password" };
//...
user = new[] { user[0], textBox1.Text };
password = new[] { password[0], textBox2.Text };
```

This is rather clumsy, though. You would probably be better off defining `user` and `password` as `List<String>`, i.e.:

```cs
public List<string> user = new List<string>() { "username" };
public List<string> password = new List<string>() { "password" };
//...
user.Add(textBox1.Text);
password.Add(textBox2.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use char array, not string array. This is because `textBox1.Text` returns a string type, not a string array type.  Calling `ToArray()` on a string results in a char array type.

```
    char[] user = textBox1.Text.ToArray();
    char[] password= textBox2.Text.ToArray();
```

You should also consider changing `string[] user` and `string[] password` to string type instead, since I'm assuming you are only storing one username in user.  If you are trying to store a collection of users, then you should name your variable correctly, such as `string[] users`, to not cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You should use char arrays instead of string array :

```
public string[] users = { "username" };
public string[] passwords = { "password" };
```

-

```
char[] users = textBox1.Text.ToArray();
char[] passwords= textBox2.Text.ToArray();
```

And instead of string arrays you can use `List<string>` for users and passwords.

Tip : It's better to rename your textBoxes something like `txtUserName` for clearify and better code.